# Java Multidimensional Arrays, How to get amount of columns to print out?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

My code is below, My task is

[image]

As you can see in my code, I have the array set at [playerCount][5],I think this is causing problems, but im not sure how to fix it.  Sometimes there might be 5 columns, and sometimes there might only be 2,3,4. There are also multiple rows, could be 1,2,3,infinity. I cant seem to figure out how to get the total of number of Rows in the column, so later i can add the values in those rows to get a sum.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ASgn8 
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("How many players? ");
    int playerCount = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
    String[] playerNames = new String[playerCount];
    Die[][] diceArray = new Die[playerCount][5];

    for(int i = 0; i < playerCount; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("What is your name: ");
        playerNames[i] = scan.nextLine();
    }

    int randomNum = (int)(Math.random() * (30-10)) +10;
    System.out.println(randomNum);
    int userChoice = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < playerCount; i++)
    {

        int j=0;
        System.out.println(playerNames[i] + "'s turn!");

        while(userChoice != 2 && j < 5) 
        {
            Die roll2 = new Die();
            roll2.roll();
            System.out.println(roll2);              
            diceArray = new Die[i][j];              
            System.out.println("Again? 1= yes, 2=no");
            userChoice = scan.nextInt();
            j++;

        }

        if(userChoice == 2)
        {
            userChoice = 1;

        }

    }

}   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you mean but you'll get the columns with `diceArray.length`and rows with `diceArray[0].length` which takes one of the arrays stored in the array and tells its size. Multi-dimensional arrays aren't really multi-dimensional arrays but more like arrays that contain arrays so you'll need to get one of the inner arrays to tell it's size.

However, you probably should use ArrayList[] instead, because normal java arrays can't be resized. Arraylists can, so you can do

`ArrayList<int> diceArray = new ArrayList()[playerNum]`.

Then init the ArrayLists with a for loop and you'll get the size with diceArray[playerNum].size(). Check for example [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_size.htm) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example:

```
String[][] array = new String[5][6];
System.out.println(array.length);
System.out.println(array[0].length);
```

I think everything will be clear.

Comment: It makes sense, however my array is set at [5] and it carries over to the end, only I don't know how to declare it as the amount the user wants to roll which is unknown until the loop, do you know of any way to fix that?